# Typescript: ensure object has certain property

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have a function

```
doSomething(param: ???) {
    param.test
}
```

How to ensure that param is an object which has `test` as a string as one of the properties?

```
const myParam = { test: '123', ... }
```

Comment: Um `doSomething(param: { test: string }) {
    param.test
}` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFAA4CGAThZgFyIDeiU2AzlAx1YUQJRMAUIhGJKNTADpWHQQF9Bg1Bhz5eJZjKiIGAcl1y+S9FlwFiGlu20MAjIcQB6R4mxUqxlWfWbrAJh1EfQdnNw8gA

Comment: Nice thanks. Actually so easy :)